# Get feature from ol.interaction.Draw on drawend

Tags: openlayers, vector, features, draw-interaction

My problem seems simple but I cannot find any questions that successfully solve it. I want to draw a circle using ol.interaction.Draw, and access the feature that is created immediately.

My code as of now is:

```
var radiusSelectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: circleLayer.getSource(),
    type: 'Circle',
    features: circleFeatures
});

radiusSelectInteraction.on('drawend', function () {
    circleFeatures.forEach(function(feature) {
        ....
    });
});
```

My problem with this is that it doesn't give me the feature that is currently being drawn. If I don't clear the vector, it will show the first circle on the drawend event of the second one I draw. I only plan on allowing 1 circle at a time so I need to access the feature on end of drawing or on end of feature add.

I tried something like this instead of drawend:

```
radiusSelectInteraction.on('drawstart', function () {
    circleLayer.getSource().once('addFeature', handleAddFeature);
});

function handleAddFeature(evt) {
    var feature = evt.feature;
    ....
}
```

but it was never triggering the **handleAddFeature** event like it was supposed to. Did I do it wrong or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best solution I've found so far is to use the current feature embedded in the event:

```
var radiusSelectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: circleLayer.getSource(),
    type: 'Circle',
    features: circleFeatures
});

radiusSelectInteraction.on('drawend', function (event) {
    var feature = event.feature;
    var features = circleLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
    features = features.concat(feature);
    features.forEach(function() {
        ....
    });
});
```